# Kinect elevation angle override

Tags: c#, kinect, angle

Is there a way to override the elevation angle property of the Kinect device?

As far as I know, the device is calculating this angle with internal sensor and using its value to improve user detection and tracking.

What I want is to mount the Kinect on the ceiling and point it straight down to the ground, then I would somehow try to set the elevation angle to 0 and fool him into thinking that it is placed in a normal position, thus maybe improving the tracking of the user that is lying on the ground underneath the sensor.

Comment: I don't think the accelerometer and motor have much to do with the user detection and tracking. That is done using the depth stream as you can see in this [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/145347/BodyPartRecognition.pdf). Ideally you would need an algorithm to detect and track people from that angle. Would something as simple as tracking blobs work ? You would use a near & far depth threshold to isolate the areas of interest and detect blobs. Blobs that are above a certain size might be humans for example.

Comment: [Here](http://lifesine.eu/rec/cv3c.mov) is an older test/proof of concept I did.